# Is there a way to determine MySQL SSL connectivity without authentication?

Tags: mysql, sql, security, ssl, database-connection

I'd like to connect to a MySQL server (AWS RDS, if you must know) via SSL. I'm familiar with the basic mechanics involved.

All the methods I've seen so far involve running a SQL query to determine that the current connection uses SSL.

My concern is that this is a "chicken and egg" problem: I would need to send my credentials to the server potentially in plain text, so I can run a query on the server to determine that it was not plain text.

Is there a way to run the `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';` query without first authenticating?

This seems like a pretty basic requirement (I'd like to know that my password will be encrypted BEFORE sending it over the wire) but it seems difficult to find the required information.

I've read the following resources:

- https://kb.berkeley.edu/page.php?id=23112
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ssl-options.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

Comment: How do you connect to the mysql server?

Comment: @mrtux: `mysql -h blah -u blah --ssl-ca=blah.pem -p` but this will always send my password, even if SSL isn't working

Comment: If you have root access to the mysql server, you could ```grant``` your user ```REQUIRE SSL``` then mysql only accepts encrypted conections.

Comment: Setting this on the server side doesn't protect you from mitm downgrade attacks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL native authentication was never sending password over network without regard of SSL usage (it always sends result of function of password and salt returned from Server instead).

In recent versions it may be beneficial to send clear text password - but that may happen only if you explicitly provide option (on client) --enable-cleartext-plugin (or similar).